# Resuming FTP downloads with inets FTP server

Tags: ftp, erlang

I have an `ftp://host/path` URL and want to download the file and resume download if connection is lost in Erlang.

Starting the download is easy enough using the [ftp](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ftp.html) module, but how can I resume it?

Comment: Doesn't look good from the documentation ... looks like you have to add it to the ftp module in the lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah.. like Peer mentioned.. you have to add the functionality into the erlang module..
I had submitted a patch for the FTP module that does exactly this :
https://gist.github.com/700908

Basically i have exposed a recv_chunk_start/3 API into the FTP module..which takes in an extra "Pos" parameter to resume FTP download from that position.

Please note.. 
1) The FTP server must understand the RETR command (some servers dont handle this -or- is dissabled)
2) this patch will work only with erlang-R13B04.. have to create a new patch for R14B.

Comment: Accepted even though I am using R14B.