# ftp client，resume broken transfer

Tags: ftp, erlang

Could you anyone tell me whether the default erlang ftp module in `erlang/lib/inets-5.9.1/src/ftp/ftp.erl` supports resume broken transfer or not?

If not, is it difficult to modify it by myself or if anyone do the modification work now?

Comment: I dont see anything [here](http://erldocs.com/R15B/inets/ftp.html) or in the source that would lead me to believe that there's any support for _resume_. I'm an erlang beginner though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resuming FTP downloads with inets FTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164701/resuming-ftp-downloads-with-inets-ftp-server)